# How to update variables in python GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface

I've been struggling on the GUI label update, it's a simple game which needs me to accomplish its GUI, the label which shows player's score and count of swaps doesn't change. I'd be more than grateful if anyone could answer my question.

```
class StatusBar(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,master):
    super().__init__(master)
    self._simple_player=SimplePlayer()

    self._swaps_label=tk.Label(self,
                               text=self._simple_player.get_swaps())
    self._score_label=tk.Label(self,
                               text=self._simple_player.get_score())
    self._swaps_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    self._score_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

class App(object):
def __init__(self, master):
    """
    Constructor(SimpleTileApp, tk.Frame)
    """
    self._master = master
    self._simple_player=SimplePlayer()
    self._game = SimpleGame()
    self._status=StatusBar(master)
    self._status.pack()

    self._grid_view = TileGridView(
        master, self._game.get_grid(),
        width=GRID_WIDTH, height=GRID_HEIGHT, bg='red')
    self._grid_view.pack(side=tk.TOP)
```

I've tried every method on Google but nothing helps

---

I rewrite a function inside the class to create a new label, but it seems to be useless

```
class StatusBar(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,master):
    super().__init__(master)
    self._simple_player=SimplePlayer()
    self._swaps_label=tk.Label(self,
                               text=self._simple_player.get_swaps())
    self._score_label=tk.Label(self,
                               text=self._simple_player.get_score())
    self._swaps_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    self._score_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


def update_label(self):
    if self._simple_player.get_swaps()==-1:
        pass
    else:

        self._swaps_label=tk.Label(self,
                               text=self._simple_player.get_swaps())
        self._score_label=tk.Label(self,
                               text=self._simple_player.get_score())
        self._swaps_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self._score_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
```

Comment: Well right now you're just defining parameters in your init function def which will run once when you instantiate an object of your class.  If you want them to update you need to define a function within your class which sets a new label and that you can call whenever an action occurs that requires a label update.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to read up on [game loops](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html). And also, have you considered using [Pygame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame)? Its has many tutorials out there, and is fairly easy to learn.